# How to find the line number using Word API?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop

I want to know the line number in the Word document from `Word.Paragraph` or `Word.Range`, but there are no suitable fields and methods.I'm using C#.

Comment: Please add some details

Answer (score 1):

Getting the line number involves using an old part of the Word object model that comes from the Word Basic days: the `Information` property. Since C# doesn't "like" properties with arguments, it's the `get_Information` method for C#

```
int lineNumberSelection = WordApp.Selection.get_Information(Word.WdInformation.wdFirstCharacterLineNumber);
int lineNumberRange = myParagraph.Range.get_Information(Word.WdInformation.wdFirstCharacterLineNumber);
```

This returns the numbering as set in the document - it's "What you see is what you get". So if the numbering is set to restart on each page or for each section or each page - that's the result returned.

If a different result is required, the numbering rule for the document must be changed (and can be changed back again, after). For example:

```
wdDocument.PageSetup.LineNumbering.RestartMode = Word.Wdnumberingrule.wdRestartContinuous;
```

Comment: Now strange numbers are output. I will try other parameters of get_Information().

Comment: What kind of "strange numbers"? There are no other parameters for ascertaining the value of line numbers. You are using Word's built-in Line Numbering feature?

Comment: My paragraph is on line 101 in document, but p.Range.get_Information() returns 28. Perhaps this is the number of the paragraph.

Comment: You actually see 101 in the margin? It won't be the number of the paragraph, but Word can be set to restart line numbering on each page, so theoretically it could be the line on the page. But in that case you should see 28 in the margin of the document.

Comment: The line number is counted from the beginning of each page. It works. Can you tell me, please, how to calculate the line number relative to the beginning of the document?

Comment: That can only be done by changing the setting so that the line numbering is continuous throughout the document. "What you see is what you get". I've added some explanation to my answer.